# Deleting GeoServer coverage store using REST API

Tags: geoserver, rest, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I was wondering if there is any example of using REST API with curl to delete a coverage store?

I looked at the examples at the boundless website http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html, and there doesn't seem to be any.

I tried:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/my_ws/coveragestores/my_cover
```

and

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/my_ws/coveragestores/my_cover?recurse=true
```

In each case, I get an `405 Method Not Allowed`.

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Output error was:

```
> DELETE /geoserver/rest/my_ws/coveragestores/my_cover?recurse=true&purge=all HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Allow: GET
< Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 01:24:28 GMT
< Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

--- EDIT ---

Additional Info:

```
$curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XGET -H "Accept: text/xml"  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_ws/coveragestores.xml
```

returns:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_ws/coveragestores.xml HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: text/xml
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 20 Oct 2014 02:53:53 GMT
< Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
<coverageStores>
  <coverageStore>
    <name>my_cover</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/my_ws/coveragestores/my_cover.xml" type="application/xml"/>
  </coverageStore>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
</coverageStores>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XDELETE http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/my_ws/coveragestores/my_cover?recurse=true
```

You have a space between `-X` and `DELETE`

Example can be seen at the [REST API Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html)

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XDELETE "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/coveragestores/polyphemus-v1/coverages/NO2/index/granules.xml?filter=location='polyphemus_20130301.nc'"
```

Additionally, the end point should be:

```
 /rest/workspaces/my_ws1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your version without the space between -X and DELETE, the result is the same. This is with GeoServer 2.5.

Comment: What coverage type are you using, what command did you use to create it?

Comment: It's a GeoTIFF image, store created with GeoServer GUI. Actually, the command gives me `405 Method Not Allowed` even if I use an non-existing coverage name such as `my_cover1`.

Comment: I suspect it is a naming issue. Use the [REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/rest/api/coverages.html) to LIST the overages and check what is actually there and what name is returned. I suspect it may be a *coverage* and not a *coverage store* that you need to refer to.

Comment: This is how to get the coverage and datastores in the work space: `curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XGET -H "Accept: text/xml"
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme`

Comment: Please see the additional info in the EDIT. Thanks. I suspect there is a naming issue too. Checking.

Comment: You are right. In `/rest/my_ws`, I missed `workspaces`. Should be `/rest/workspaces/my_ws` ... Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Welcome. I will update my answer for future users as well.